Reference or proof of application of multivariate Donsker's theorem
Let $f : \mathbb{R^d} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded Lipshcitz function. I am looking for a reference or a proof of the (hopefully true) fact that
$$ \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N f \left( \frac{S_n}{|| S_n||} \right) \to \int_0^1 dt \ f \left( \frac{B_t}{|| B_t ||}\right)$$
weakly in the limit as $N \to \infty$, where $B_t$ is a standard $d$-dimensional Brownian motion, $S_n := \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, and $(X_i)$ are $\mathbb{R}^d$-valued i.i.d. random variables with vanishing mean and variance $I$.
I have the following reference, which does not have a direct proof of the given result, but I am unsure if it is standard or if there is a different treatment somewhere else that would be more all encompassing.

$N$ should be $n$?
